# Group the objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

Need to check does "X" or "O" has more occurrences. The values of the array possibilities should be compared against the row value of the moves array. As we find the value of the occurrence reaches 3, we need to stop the iteration.

```
 const possibilities = [
            [0, 1, 2],
            [3, 4, 5],
            ...
      ];

 const moves = [{
        "row": 0,
        "type": "X",
    },
    {
        "row": 1,
        "type": "O",
    },
    {
        "row": 2,
        "type": "O",
    },
    {
        "row": 3,
        "type": "X",
    },
    {
        "row": 4,
        "type": "O",
    },
    {
        "row": 5,
        "type": "X",
    }];
```

Code as follows:

```
let count = 0;
possibilities.forEach((possibility) => {
    let type = null;
    for (let index = 0; index < possibility.length; index++) {
        console.log(possibility[index], "index")
        for (let j = 0; j < moves; j++) {
            if (moves[j].row === possibility[index]) {
                console.log(moves[j], "j")
                if (type === null) {
                    type = moves[j].type;
                } else if (type === moves[j].type) {
                    ++count;
                } else {
                    type = null;
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Does your code works and you need a speedup?

Comment: So you are trying to iterate through possibilities and if the row matches with on item in the array the occurrence of (for example X) grows by one. And if it hits 3 stop the iteration and return X or O(witch has 3 times accuracy)?

Comment: yeah, you are right

Comment: Can you post an example of the desired result?

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' the type "X" or "O" reaches the value 3 first, that type will be considered as the winner. So, I just need count value of `type` which is equivalent to 3.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you.
If this did not work. Please write a comment. So I can edit my answer.

This code is not fully optimized!! But I can do that if the code works for you.

```js
let counts = {}
for(const possibility of possibilities) {
    for(const move of moves) {
        if(possibility.includes(move.row)) {
            if(!(move.type in counts)) counts[move.type] = 0
            counts[move.type]++
        }
    }
}
console.log(counts)

let heightsValue = -1
let heightsType = '-'
for(const type in counts) {
    if(counts[type] > heightsValue) {
        heightsType = type
        heightsValue = counts[type]
    }
}
console.log(heightsType)
```

Comment: It's not working. When I update the moves column value of null into a certain value. The count object undetermined increments. Here is the code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-pine-ygkk0

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to iterate over possibilities to see if at least 3 of their moves are type 'X'.

Predispositions...

```js
const possibilities = [
    [0, 1, 2], // ['X', 'O', 'O'] -> false
    [3, 4, 5], // ['X', 'O', 'X'] -> false
    [0, 3, 5], // ['X', 'X', 'X'] -> true
];

const moves = [{
    "row": 0,
    "type": "X",
}, {
    "row": 1,
    "type": "O",
}, {
    "row": 2,
    "type": "O",
}, {
    "row": 3,
    "type": "X",
}, {
    "row": 4,
    "type": "O",
}, {
    "row": 5,
    "type": "X",
}];
```

1. match moves

```js
let result = possibilities.map((possibility) => 
  possibility.map((row) => moves.find(r => r.row === row).type)
);

// [ [ 'X', 'O', 'O' ], [ 'X', 'O', 'X' ], [ 'X', 'X', 'X' ] ]
```

2. find out how many Xs

```js
result = result.map((posibility) =>
  posibility.filter(moveType => moveType === 'X').length
);

// [1, 2, 3]
```

2. compare there at at least 3 Xs

```js
result = result.map((xMoves) => xMoves >= 3);

// [false, false, true]
```

All in one

```
let result = possibilities.map((possibility) => 
  possibility.map((row) => moves.find(r => r.row === row).type)
             .filter(moveType => moveType === 'X')
             .length >= 3
);

// [false, false, true]
```

The 3rd values in possibilities (`possibilities[2]` is the winner)

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-pine-ygkk0

Comment: That's because in codesandbox.io/s/holy-pine-ygkk0, all `move` objects have numerical `id`, but `row:null`. Either identify them with `row`, or modify the `find` function to `r => r.id === row`. See either https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-germain-byszv or https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-payne-j22dn